# What is a faster way to iterate through a numpy array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am wondering if there is a better way to iterate through numpy arrays?
I have timed my nested iterations and it takes roughly about 40-50 seconds per loop, and i am wondering if there is a faster way to do it? I know that looping through numpy arrays is not ideal, however I'm out of ideas. I looked through many questions on Stack Overflow but all of them ends up confusing me even more.

I have tried converting the numpy array to a list using the `tolist()` function, however the run time is equally slower, if not worse.

```
def euc_distance(array1, array2):
    return np.power(np.sum((array1 - array2)**2) , 0.5)

for i in range(N):
    for j,n in enumerate(data2.values): 
        distance = euc_distance(n, D[i]) 
        if distance < Dradius[i] and NormAttListTest[j] == "Attack":
            TP += 1
```

My euc_distance function passes in an array form (In my case, 5 dimensional) inputs, to output a 1 dimensional value. My `data2.values` is my way of access the numpy array through the pandas framework which is a [500 000, 5] dataframe.

(Note that the NormAttListTest is a list that has the categorical data of "Attack" and "Normal" tagged to each individual testing data).

Comment: The fastest way to iterate through the array is to do the iterations in compiled code - with the `numpy` methods provided, or custom ones written in `numba` or `cython`.  Python level iterations are generally about the same speed, give or take 2x.  If you must iterate, worry more about the speed of what you are doing inside the iteration, and less about the iteration mechanism (the wrapper) itself.

Comment: @hpaulj Can you explain what is the meaning of a compiled code? Thank you.

Comment: Could you provide the exact shapes of every array involved in this computation? That would really help understand that you're doing and to vectorize the entire thing, which is what "using the compiled code" means.

Comment: I have realised my mistake. I should not have iterated through every row in the numpy array and instead should have just calculated in its array form. Thanks for the help though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you use `numpy` in a wrong way because `numpy` is all about vectorized computations like `MATLAB`. Consider the following modification of your code. I replaced your loop over numpy array with plain numpy code that efficiently utilizes vectorization for 2d arrays. As a result code runs 100 times faster.

```
import functools
import numpy as np
import time

# decorator to measure running time
def measure_running_time(echo=True):
    def decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            t_1 = time.time()
            ans = func(*args, **kwargs)
            t_2 = time.time()
            if echo:
                print(f'{func.__name__}() running time is {t_2 - t_1:.2f} s')
            return ans
        return wrapped
    return decorator


def euc_distance(array1, array2):
    return np.power(np.sum((array1 - array2) ** 2), 0.5)

# original function
@measure_running_time()
def calculate_TP_1(N, data2, D, Dradius, NormAttListTest, TP=0):
    for i in range(N):
        for j, n in enumerate(data2):
            distance = euc_distance(n, D[i])
            if distance < Dradius[i] and NormAttListTest[j] == "Attack":
                TP += 1
    return TP

# new version
@measure_running_time()
def calculate_TP_2(N, data2, D, Dradius, NormAttListTest, TP=0):

    # this condition is the same for every i value
    NormAttListTest = np.array([val == 'Attack' for val in NormAttListTest])

    for i in range(N):

        # don't use loop over numpy arrays

        # compute distance for all the rows
        distance = np.sum((data2 - D[i]) ** 2, axis=1) ** .5
        # check conditions for all the row
        TP += np.sum((distance < Dradius[i]) & (NormAttListTest))

    return TP


if __name__ == '__main__':

    N = 10
    NN = 100_000
    D = np.random.randint(0, 10, (N, 5))
    Dradius = np.random.randint(0, 10, (N,))
    NormAttListTest = ['Attack'] * NN
    NormAttListTest[:NN // 2] = ['Defence'] * (NN // 2)
    data2 = np.random.randint(0, 10, (NN, 5))

    print(calculate_TP_1(N, data2, D, Dradius, NormAttListTest))

    print(calculate_TP_2(N, data2, D, Dradius, NormAttListTest))
```

Output:

```
calculate_TP_1() running time is 7.24 s
96476
calculate_TP_2() running time is 0.06 s
96476
```

Comment: My apologies for not making the question clear enough, however the NormAttListTest is actually a list that is read from a CSV file, hence it has a corresponding Attack/Normal tagged to every individual data that is being tested. However may i know what is the main lesson here?

Comment: @Axois It dosn't really matter. Then you just have to handle `NormAttListTest` inside `for i in range(N)` loop. The point is to avoid loops over numpy arrays because numpy can treat arrays much faster than plain python.

Comment: Update: I have managed to reduce the run-time to about 100 times by not iterating through the arrays individually and instead added the axis=1 parameter in my distance calculation function such that i am able to input my entire array of data. Thanks a lot! However can you explain what does it mean if i set axis = 1? Does it take every row?

Comment: @Axois I guess you added `axis=1` into `np.sum(...)` function. This means to find sum for every row of 2d array (10 rows - 10 sums). Default value is `axis=None` means to find sum of all the elements in array (10 rows - 1 sum). See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html